# if then do in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have created 3 functions.  Each connects to a database, runs a query and displays the result.  Run indivually they all work fine.  However I want the user to decide which report of 3+ to run, to do so they will select a parameter and hit an execute button.  How do I write a nested if then do in Clojure to decide which functions to execute?

If param = "reporta"
do execute functiona
else if param = "reportb"
do execute functionb
else etc
etc
etc

I have searched online but can't really find a good example of what I am trying to do... Any advise much appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Use `cond` or [condp](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/condp):

```
(condp = param
  "reporta"    (functiona)
  "reportb"    (functionb)
  (function-else))
```

Alternatively, you could use a map of functions and just index by param.

Comment: In that case you can also use `case` since the compared things are literals.

Comment: I always forget about `case`. It betrayed me once (classes aren't literals) so I never went back :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `case` for your problem:

```
(case param
  "reporta" (do-something-a)
  "reportb" (do-something-b)
  (else-case))
```